# Explicit type signatures for polymorphic types

Tags: haskell

I'm reviewing *Haskell: The Craft of Functional Programming*, however the type signatures on page 356 have thrown me for a loop.

Here is a simple one:

```
succeed :: b -> Parse a b
succeed val inp = [( val, inp )]
```

How can that be `b -> Parse a b`, if

```
succeed Int -> Int
succeed a = a
```

and,

```
succeed Int -> Int -> Int
succeed a b = a + b
```

The amount of arguments your taking has to be in the type declaration right? How can you take `val`, and `imp`, if your type declaration only has one type variable: `succeed :: b -> Parse a b` is supposed to read, take one variable of type `a` and return a type of `Parse a b`, not take two variables... where is `inp` permitted?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `Parse` is a type synonym with `->` in its expansion.  Example:

```
type Foo = Int -> Int

succeed :: Int -> Foo
succeed a b = a + b
```

Comment: I looked dazed at this for a while, the explicit mention of a synonym with `->` was certainly helpful. I understand what you mean now, this seems to rather obscure the clarity of the type system -- could you or someone else comment on this affect..

Comment: @Evan: Writing `succeed`'s type with that shortcut makes it explicit you probably want to apply that function to two arguments. You're supposed to apply it to one argument so it produces a parser (aka function). It could have been defined with only with argument on the left side, like this `succeed val = \inp -> [(val, inp)]`, i.e., takes an argument `val` and produces a *parser* (aka function) that takes `inp` and produces that list. It just happens that a parser is actually a function. Because you can easily compose functions, you can easily compose parsers written in this style.

Comment: I wish the book was this explicit about what was happening

Answer (score 1):

In Haskell all functions take exactly one argument and produce exactly one result. When have a type like this `a -> b -> c` you have the same as `a -> (b -> c)`. So, instead of a two-argument function, you actually have a function that when given an argument produces another function that takes the second argument and produces the final result.

When you apply a function to two arguments, like this `f x y`, it's the same as `(f x) y`. You're actually applying the function that results from `f x` to the second argument `y`. From this behavior you get "partial application" for free.

There is a pair of functions in the Prelude named `curry` and `uncurry` that let you convert between functions written in this style and functions that take two arguments directly as a pair:

```
uncurry :: (a -> b -> c) -> ((a,b) -> c)
curry :: ((a,b) -> c) -> (a -> b -> c)

f  :: a -> b -> c
f = ...
f' :: (a,b) -> c
f' = uncurry f
```

I don't know how `Parse` was defined, but if you define it as a synonym to a function type (something common with parsers), you get that kind of behavior.