# Explicit type signatures for polymorphic types. Part II

Tags: haskell, types, polymorphism, type-synonyms

This is a follow up to a [previous question; I got an answer I didn't really understand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974025/explicit-type-signatures-for-polymorphic-types), but accepted. So I'll ask it again.

I still don't understand how this makes sense:

```
type Parse a b = [a] -> [(b,[a])]
build :: Parse a b -> ( b -> c ) -> Parse a c
build p f inp = [ (f x, rem) | (x, rem) <- p inp ]
```

Now, obviously, `p` binds to the first argument of type `Parse a b`. And, again obviously `f` binds to the second argument `(b -> c)`. My question remains what does `inp` bind to?

If `Parse a b` is a type synonym for `[a] -> [(b,[a])]` I thought from the last question I could just substitute it:

```
build :: [a] -> [(b,[a])] -> ( b -> c ) -> [a] -> [(c,[a])]
```

However, I don't see that making any sense either with the definition:

```
build p f inp = [ (f x, rem) | (x, rem) <- p inp ]
```

Would someone explain type synonyms?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Now, obviously, p binds to the first argument of type Parse a b. And, again obviously f binds to the second argument (b -> c). My question remains what does inp bind to?

The argument of type `[a]`

> If Parse a b is a type synonym for [a] -> [(b,[a])] I thought from the last question I could just substitute it:
>
> ```
> build :: [a] -> [(b,[a])] -> ( b -> c ) -> [a] -> [(c,[a])]
> ```

Almost; you need to parenthesize the substitutions:

```
build :: ([a] -> [(b,[a])]) -> ( b -> c ) -> ([a] -> [(c,[a])])
```

Because `->` is right-associative you can remove the parentheses at the end, but not at the beginning, so you get:

```
build :: ([a] -> [(b,[a])]) -> ( b -> c ) -> [a] -> [(c,[a])]
```

This should make it obvious why `inp` has type `[a]`.

Answer (score 5):

You can substitute -- but don't forget to bracket!  That should be:

```
build :: ( [a] -> [(b,[a])] ) -> ( b -> c ) -> ( [a] -> [(c,[a])] )
```

Because the function arrow is right-associative you can dump the right-hand set of brackets, but crucially you cannot discard the new ones on the left:

```
build :: ( [a] -> [(b,[a])] ) -> ( b -> c ) -> [a] -> [(c,[a])]
```

So now when you have the line `build p f inp`, you can see that:

```
p :: ( [a] -> [(b,[a])] )
f :: ( b -> c )
inp :: [a]
```

So then we can see that:

```
p inp :: [(b, [a])]
```

And thus:

```
x :: b
rem :: [a]
```

And:

```
f x :: c
(f x, rem) :: (c, [a])
```

And hence the whole list comprehension has type `[(c, [a])]` -- which neatly matches what `build` should return.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 4):

If you substitute

```
type Parse a b = [a] -> [(b,[a])]
```

into

```
build :: Parse a b -> ( b -> c ) -> Parse a c
```

you get

```
build :: ([a] -> [(b,[a])]) -> (b -> c) -> [a] -> [(c,[a])]
```

Remember that `x -> y -> z` is shorthand for `x -> (y -> z)` which is very different from `(x -> y) -> z`. The first is a function that takes two arguments `x`, `y` and returns `z` [precisely it takes one argument x and returns a function, that takes y and returns z]; the second is something that takes a *function* `x -> y` and returns `z`.

Answer (score 3):

The important thing to remember here is that the arrow `->` in type signatures is right associative. The type `a -> (b -> c)` is the same as the type `a -> b -> c`.

So the type

```
Parse a b -> ( b -> c ) -> Parse a c
```

resolves to

```
([a] -> [(b,[a])]) -> ( b -> c ) -> ([a] -> [(c,[a])])
```

By associativity, you can remove the last parens, but not the first. That gives you

```
([a] -> [(b,[a])]) -> ( b -> c ) -> [a] -> [(c,[a])]
```

which allows you to write a formula for `build` with 3 arguments.